# The Web MIDI API is not supported by your browser - Google Chrome on Mac - when code is run locally

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-midi

Folks,

I am trying work on a simple Web MIDI app.

I already looked up and found out that Google Chrome is the only browser that supports this. So, I installed this but I still get this.

> WebMidi could not be enabled Error: The Web MIDI API is not supported
>   by your browser.
>       at WebMidi.enable (webmidi.min.js:30)
>       at script.js:430 (anonymous)  @   script.js:432 WebMidi.enable    @   webmidi.min.js:30 (anonymous)   @   script.js:430
>   Promise.then (async)       (anonymous)    @   script.js:154

Mac - 10.15.2
Chrome - 79.0.3945.117

According to this link - https://www.midi.org/17-the-mma/99-web-midi , Chrome definitely has the support.

Important Note - If I were run the code directly on codepen, it works just fine. So the browser is working. But when I try to run locally, I get the error.

https://codepen.io/teropa/pen/JLjXGK

```
  WebMidi.enable(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('WebMidi could not be enabled', err);
      return;
    }
```

What am I missing here? is this a chrome issue or Mac issue or some permission issue. Or, is there is something specific I need to make the MIDI code run locally?

I am using this server, https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server, to run the code locally.

(I have looked at other questions but did not find anything that relates to Chrome on Mac)

Comment: When using address 0.0.0.0 I see this same error, but when loading from 127.0.0.1 it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used web-midi with Chromium and Opera on 10.12.6, so I wouldn't say that Chrome is the *only* browser that has web-midi.

With Opera I think I had to enable experimental features:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features
```

Maybe see if Chrome needs that too?
Or maybe it's just a side-effect of all the lock-down in 10.15?

Comment: I will give it a go with Opera, and see if it makes a difference. Just to emphasize, I am able to run this directly on codepen. It gives that error only when I try to run locally. But I will see if the issue is the same with Opera. I have a suspicion that it is something to do with running these libraries locally.

Answer (score 2):

if serving dev site from 0.0.0.0 you won't get any MIDI in browser, but when loading from 127.0.0.1 it should work ( as commented by user Alex above )